# natToFin when there is evidence that the conversion will work

Tags: idris

The `natToFin` function from the standard library has the following signature:

```
natToFin : Nat -> (n : Nat) -> Maybe (Fin n)
```

`natToFin 4 5` returns `Just (FS (FS (FS (FS FZ)))) : Maybe (Fin 5)`, while 
`natToFin 5 5` returns `Nothing`.

I would like a function with the following signature:

```
myNatToFin : (m : Nat) -> (n : Nat) -> { auto p : n `GT` m } -> Fin n
```

It behaves the same as the standard lib function but doesn't need to return a `Maybe` because it is always possible to generate a `Fin n` from `m` given that `n` is greater than `m`.

How do I implement `myNatToFin`?

Answer (score 5):

You can do it directly by recursing on `m`, `n`, and the evidence for `` n `GT` m `` at the same time:

```
import Data.Fin

myNatToFin : (m : Nat) -> (n : Nat) -> {auto p : n `GT` m} -> Fin n
myNatToFin Z (S n) = FZ
myNatToFin (S m) (S n) {p = LTESucc _} = FS $ myNatToFin m n
```

Note that you need to pattern match on `p` in the second case (even though its value is not used on the right-hand side) so that the automatic argument for the recursive call can be filled in.