# How do I provide an implicit argument explicitly?

Tags: idris

Suppose I have a function with this signature:

```
myNatToFin : (m : Nat) -> (n : Nat) -> { auto p : n `GT` m } -> Fin n
```

I try to apply it like this `myNatToFin k (S k)` in the body of another function and I get the error:

```
Can't solve goal 
            GT (S k) k
```

So, I believe I have to explicitly pass a proof that `GT (S k) k`, but I have no idea how to do this.  How can I explicitly pass the implicit proof argument so that this compiles?

Answer (score 3):

You can give explicit arguments for implicit parameters by enclosing them in braces and prefixing with the parameter name, like `{p = someExpression foo}`.

Full example:

```
import Data.Fin

myNatToFin : (m : Nat) -> (n : Nat) -> { auto p : n `GT` m } -> Fin n
myNatToFin m n = ?x -- See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29908731/

lteRefl : LTE n n
lteRefl {n = Z} = LTEZero
lteRefl {n = S _} = LTESucc lteRefl    

foo : (k : Nat) -> Fin (S k)
foo k = myNatToFin k (S k) {p = LTESucc lteRefl}
```